# Unable to change the text of an anchor using javascript

Tags: javascript, anchor

I need to alter an anchor tag, see the code below.

```
document.getElementById("stationid").href=urlst;
document.getElementById("stationid").innerHTLM=stdesc;  //I also tried text=stdesc
```

The href works but the text that is displayed by the  tag remains unchanged.

In my many googles none specifically say that the displayed text is accessed via innerHTML but as in so many examples of web development it is assumed you know these things.

I have tried to google what the field is called (so I could use ...displayedText=stdesc) with no success. One implied it was nodeValue but that did not work either.

Please help.

Comment: Spelling mistake in `document.getElementById("stationid").innerHTLM=stdesc;` innerHTML is written as innerHTLM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling mistake in

```
document.getElementById("stationid").innerHTLM=stdesc;
```

`innerHTML` is written as `innerHTLM`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("stationid").innerHTLM=stdesc;

                                           ^^^^
                              here is your problem its `HTML`
```